# Transforming categorical land use raster to raster with continuous values

Tags: raster, r, terra, land-use, esa

I would like to transform categorical land use rasters from ESA CCI (http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/download.php) to rasters with continuous values (% of cover of each land use class in each cell).

The resolution of that data is 300 m and the crs is lon/lat WGS 84. I am thinking about aggregating to a coarser resolution so the cells can have more than one LULC class.

I would like to use R to do this but I don't know how procceed, specially taking into account that each cell has a different surface because of the crs.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have a set of NxM rasters of each LU category, and you want to aggregate up to PxQ where the value in each cell of that raster is the proportion of cells in that LU category in the original raster, weighted by cell area? (Note that terra::cellSize gets the cell areas of spherical geometry cells in m^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data with four classes

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
set.seed(1)
values(r) <- sample(1:4, 100, replace=TRUE)
```

A solution is to use `segregate` to get a layer for each class. Then `aggregate` the layers with the mean function to get the fraction of each class in each aggregated cell.

```
b <- segregate(r)
frac <- aggregate(b, 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```