# Categorical land use raster to continuous values raster in R

Tags: raster, r, terra, land-use

I would like to transform categorical land use rasters from ESA CCI (http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/download.php) to rasters with continuous values. The crs is lon/lat WGS 84 and I would like to maintain the original resolution, 300 m.

The original idea was aggregating cells ([Transforming categorical land use raster to raster with continuous values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/471737/transforming-categorical-land-use-raster-to-raster-with-continuous-values)) but I would rather keep a finer resolution.

Is taking the ESA-CCI rasters, segregating each land use category (so each raster has values of 0 or 1 per cell) and then substituting the values "1" for the size of the cell, a good approach? If so, how can I do this when the size of each cell is different due to the crs being lon/lat WGS84?

Comment: Please include a *self-contained, minimal, reproducible example* when asking R questions. I already showed you how to do that here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/472978/8993

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create rasters for each category, where the values represent the cell area, you can multiply each cell with its area. You should compute the cell size, irrespective of whether the coordinate reference system (CRS) is lonlat or something else. This is because, due to distortion introduced by flattening the earth, the raster cell sizes also vary with most planar CRSs.

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrows=10, ncols=10)
set.seed(1)
values(r) <- sample(1:4, 100, replace=TRUE)
```

Solution

```
s <- segregate(r)
a <- cellSize(s, unit="km") / 100000
x <- s * a
```